# gallery doesn't response for touch event using x y

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

i just use chimchat to do android UI automation. 
everything goes well except when i touch a image from gallery using xy position
are there any differences?
anybody help?

Comment: Can you post that code that you're using to try to touch the image? It's hard to figure out whats wrong without being able to see the code first.

Comment: very simple code. monkeydevice.press(x,y,type). i get x,y value using hierarchy viewer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using `monkeydevice.press(x,y,MonkeyDevice.DOWN)` then `sleep(.1)` and finally `monkeydevice.press(x,y,MonkeyDevice.UP)`. It might be that your not touching the spot long enough for anything to register.